# Stuck in a redirect loop from RewriteCond/RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Im trying to create a maintenance page for my website and have added the following to .htaccess

```
##SETTINGS##
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Allow From All

RewriteCond         %{REMOTE_ADDR}      !^00\.00\.00\.00
RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_URI}      !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css) [NC]
RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/maintenance.php [NC]
RewriteRule         .*                  /maintenance.php [R=302,L]

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 1 week"
</IfModule>

## ADDITIONAL REWRITE RULES BELOW HERE ##
```

This works on my local MAMP environment but when i upload it to my hosting provider (GoDaddy) it gets stuck in an infinite redirect loop and the maintenance page wont load. Changing the first line to my own ip address allows me access to the site (as intended) but others still get stuck in the redirect loop.

I followed the guide at [moz.com](http://moz.com/blog/how-to-handle-downtime-during-site-maintenance) with a few alterations to get images and css loading on the maintenance page.

Please Help a n00b in need...

EDIT: Added the top of my .htaccess so people don't think thats why its not working

EDIT2: Added all other redirect rules as requested

EDIT3: Removed additional redirect rules as not relevant to question

Comment: What are your other rewrite rules?

Comment: All the other rewrites are working fine and i cant see any that would cause a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, those rules look pretty correct. In fact, in addition to running them locally, you can always lint them using something like http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

In this instance, I would recommend reaching out to GoDaddy about the issue. It's possible that they have another config set globally for your account which is affecting your rules.

Comment: I may have to bite the bullet and give Godaddy a call, time for alot of waiting...

Answer (score 0):

The rules look fine, but my guess is either your other rules are redirecting back to something other than maintenance.php or your maintenance.php file is redirecting to somewhere. Try adding this right below the `Allow From All` line:

```
RewriteRule ^maintenance.php - [L]
```

so that your other rules won't get applied.

Comment: Problem here is that i also get redirected to maintenance.php. Ideally i still need to be able to access the site during the maintenance.

Comment: @UndeadGeek this rule doesn't redirect anything. It just says "if the URL **is** `/maintenance.php`, don't do anything"

Comment: @UndeadGeek looks like those rules isn't causing the redirect loop. Are you sure something in maintenance.php isn't redirecting?

Comment: after adding your rule i was still being redirected to the maintenance page even though my IP was specified in the second RewriteCond. There is also nothing in maintenance.php just these headers:  header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily   Unavailable");
header("Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");  
header("Retry-After: 3600");

Comment: I seem to have fixed it now anyway by removing the [R] flag on the RewriteRule, thank you for the help though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the [R] flag on the RewriteRule has fixed the redirect loop. I also had to removed the forward slash before the page name as that created a Server error once i had removed the [R] flag due to the RewriteBase already being set to "/".

The maintenance page is now displaying correctly and i can access the whole site from my own IP address.

Changed

```
RewriteRule    .*    /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule    .*    maintenance.php [L]
```

Guess it must have been some weird GoDaddy settings, at least it saves me calling them...

Thank you for the help Chris and Jon Lin :)